# How do I add parameter in g:actionSubmit in Grails

Tags: grails

This is my view

```
<g:textArea name="review"/>
<g:actionSubmit action="addReview" params="${[gameId : "${game.id}", gameTitle : "${game.gameTitle}"] }" value="Add Review" class="ui blue labeled submit icon button">
    <i class="icon edit"></i> Add Review
</g:actionSubmit>
```

In my addReview action when I do `log.println(review)` It works but when I do `log.println(gameTitle)` and `log.println(gameId)`, it is `null`.
I'm pretty sure `${game.gameTitle}` and `${game.gameTitle}` isn't null because it prints something when I put it on GSP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Tags/actionSubmit.html

you can not add parameters in g:actionSubmit tag.
try like this:

```
<g:textArea name="review"/>
<input name="gameId" value="${game.id}" type="hidden" />
<input name="gameTitle" value="${game.gameTitle}" type="hidden" />
<g:actionSubmit action="addReview" value="Add Review" class="ui blue labeled submit icon button">
          <i class="icon edit"></i> Add Review
 </g:actionSubmit>
```